# How to remap Caps Lock to a specific key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, setxkbmap

By default I have the following key mapping:

```
$ xmodmap -pke
...
keycode  49 = oe OE oe OE leftdoublequotemark rightdoublequotemark leftdoublequotemark
...
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
...
```

I assigned <kbd>Ctlr</kbd> to keycode 66 by doing `$ setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"`

Now I'd like to assign <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to keycode 49.

I did:

```
$ printf "keycode  49 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" > ~/.Xmodmap
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

The result was that pressing keycode  49 activates <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> but pressing it again doesn't deactivate <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>...

How could I toggle <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> by pressing keycode 49?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the set up mentioned in the question, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> can be activated by pressing keycode 49 and desactivated by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + keycode 49.